# Does it hold that $z \in \{\{A \setminus B\} \cup \{B \setminus A\}\}^c \implies z \in A \cap B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we have that

$$
x \in A \setminus B \qquad \text{and} \qquad y \in B \setminus A
$$

is there a more concise way of denoting what $x$ and $y$ can be in? For example, since both represent items in one set and not the other, their complement must be contained in both sets? In other words:

$$
z \in \{\{A \setminus B\} \cup \{B \setminus A\}\}^c \implies z \in A \cap B
$$

Comment: You can try this with a Venn diagram.  Answer: no.  Can you see why?

Comment: What do you mean by the complement of two elements of a set?

Comment: I guess these might just be parenthesis instead of surly braces. Anyway use $U\setminus V=U\cap V^\complement$ and De Morgan Laws (see a cheatsheet here https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCuYr.png.

Comment: The curly braces $\{\}$ should not be used as grouping symbols here, given the set theory context. Writing $\{A \setminus B\} \cup \{B \setminus A\}$ indicates the union of the two sets $\{A \setminus B\}$ and $\{B \setminus A\}$, each containing a single element, to get the (at most) two-element set $\{A \setminus B, B \setminus A\}$. If you use parentheses instead, i.e. $(A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$, then you get the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$, i.e. the set of all elements in $A$ or $B$ but not both.

Comment: True only if $A\cup B$ is entire space.

Comment: I suspect you meant $z \in ((A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A))^c$ rather than $z \in \{\{A \setminus B\} \cup \{B \setminus A\}\}^c.$ The latter is a set with only one member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches to this.

**Common sense:** $A\setminus B$ contains everything that is in $A$ but not in $B$. Similarly, $B\setminus A$ contains everything that is in $B$ but not in $A$. Therefore, $(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$ contains everything that is in *precisely one* of $A$ or $B$, but not both. Upon negating this last condition, we can conclude that $[(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)]^{\mathsf c}$ contains everything that is *either* (i) both in $A$ and in $B$; *or* (ii) neither in $A$ nor in $B$. Formally: $$[(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)]^{\mathsf c}=(A\cap B)\cup(A^{\mathsf c}\cap B^{\mathsf c}).$$

**De Morgan, distributivity, and the definition of the $\setminus$ operation:**
\begin{align*}
&[(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)]^{\mathsf c}\\
{}={}&[(A\cap B^{\mathsf c})\cup(B\cap A^{\mathsf c})]^{\mathsf c}\\
{}={}&[(A\cap B^{\mathsf c})]^{\mathsf c}\cap[(B\cap A^{\mathsf c})]^{\mathsf c}\\
{}={}&(A^{\mathsf c}\cup B)\cap(B^{\mathsf c}\cup A)\\
{}={}&(A^{\mathsf c}\cap B^{\mathsf c})\cup\underbrace{(A^{\mathsf c}\cap A)}_{=\varnothing}\cup\underbrace{(B\cap B^{\mathsf c})}_{=\varnothing}\cup(B\cap A)\\
{}={}&(A\cap B)\cup(A^{\mathsf c}\cap B^{\mathsf c})
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\{A \backslash B\} = A$ and $\{B \backslash A\} = B$ meaning $A\cap B = \{ \}$. Then, it is clear that $$\{\{A \backslash B\}\cup\{B \backslash A\}\}^c = \{A\cup B\}^c \neq A\cap B$$